# Unable to get xpath for screen scraping

Tags: python, xpath, screen-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the tables of contents from this website, http://www.soccerstats.com/latest.asp?league=england . I'm using scrapy in python to get the details inside this table.

```
<div id="league-table-data" style="text-align:center;clear:both;">
        </div>
```

I have tried many xpath expressions. For a start, i'm just trying to get the team names first in that table using

```
hxs.select('//div[contains(@id, "league-table")]/div[descendant::td[contains(@align, "left")]]/a/text()').extract()
```

However, it is returning a empty list. Any ideas how i can make it work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need need:

```
>>> hxs.select('//*[@id="league-table-data"]/table/tr/td/a/text()').extract() 
[u'Manchester Utd', u'Manchester City', u'Chelsea', u'Arsenal', u'Tottenham', u'Everton', u'Liverpool', u'West Bromwich', u'Swansea City', u'West Ham Utd', u'Norwich City', u'Fulham', u'Stoke City', u'Southampton', u'Aston Villa', u'Newcastle Utd', u'Sunderland', u'Wigan Athletic', u'Reading', u'QP Rangers']
```

[**Quick Tip:** Getting The XPath In Google Chrome.](http://youtu.be/vCNLPHP3E_U)

Comment: Thanks. I followed the video and got //*[@id="league-table-data"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a . Why is there a need to remove "tbody" to get the values i need? E.g. "Manchester Utd" in this case.

Comment: Scrapy suggests removing <tbody>. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/firefox.html